# Boolean values in local language

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, locale, windows-7-x64

This question has been asked long time ago on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/274964/iis-7-5-using-classic-asp-converts-a-boolean-value-to-a-string-in-the-local-lang) but no working awnser. I'm hoping somebody has encountered it and found a solution since then.

Example:

```
<%
Response.Write True
Response.Write "<hr>"
Response.Write "test:" & True
%>
```

Output:

```
True
--------------
test:Waar
```

As you can see, as soon as you combine the output, its turned into a local string ('Waar' is dutch for true). I need it to stay "True".

How can I change this? I dont mind putting some code at the beginning of the pages, but I cannot change all instances of `True` in the entire code. So creating a function like below to return the correct string wont do.

```
Function PB(pVal)
  If pVal Then
    PB = "true"
  Else
    PB = "false"
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: May i know, what output u r expecting ?

Comment: Always just true. So the second response should be `test:True`

Comment: Unfortunately none of the answers were correct or solved the issue. But I feel @gpinkas put most effort into finding a solution and had some ideas I couldnt discard right away.

Comment: @HugoDelsing not sure if you have solved this but another thing came to my mind: have you tried to use a specific windows user for IIS instead of the IUSR? then try to change the locale settings of that user. i have not tried this so i am not sure if that helps

Comment: Just gave it a try, but its not working. Text stays in dutch. Thanks for the effort though

Answer (score 4):

Strange, I cannot get my IIS to output a boolean value in my local language no matter which locale is set.

Did you find this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306044) already?

There is a description of a registry setting that could do the trick:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OLEAUT
```

I don't want to mess with my production server, so I didn't try this yet.

---

**FIRST ANSWER:**

You could 'trick' VB to use your own functions. If you add these functions to the top of your page, VB will prefer these over the builtin ones, in this case `CStr` and `Trim`. Maybe this helps.

```
    Function PB(pVal)
        If pVal Then
            PB = "true"
        Else
            PB = "false"
        End If
    End Function

    Function CStr(pVal)
        CStr = PB(pVal)
    End Function

    Function Trim(pVal)
        Trim = PB(pVal)
    End Function
```

Output:

```
    True
    --------------
    test:true
    --------------
    test:true
    --------------
    test:true
```

Comment: Basically you're doing an override. Tested this in VB (I don't have Classic ASP setup on my system). The Trim() worked, but the CStr() gave me a syntax error. But Str() also worked.

Comment: Yes, I tested this in classic ASP (IIS 7.5), there was no syntax error. It's not the cleanest solution for sure, but you might work with it.

Comment: The use of Cstr and Trim were a result of another awnser that said it was the solution. I'm using just `True` without any method around it. The change should be by changing some server setting. Either via ASP or directly in IIS7

Comment: Hi, I have been testing with it, but changing the locale had no effect on the value. ALtering the registry didnt seem to have any effect either. Probably because I'm logged in on the server and the settings override the default behaviour when nobody is logged in.

Comment: Its reassuring when the default behavior is described in the MS-KB as being "completely random"... BTW, I also tried to set the culture in a web.config file, nothing changed by this either. :(

Answer (score 3):

I do something like this, but currently don't have a machine to test your case:

```
<%
Response.Write FormatDateTime(Now) & "<br />"
oldLocale = SetLocale(1026) 'Bulgarian
Response.Write FormatDateTime(Now) & "<br />"
SetLocale oldLocale 
Response.Write FormatDateTime(Now) & "<br />"
%>
```

... from another SO question, it looks the above doesn't work.

What hapopens if you try these:
`Response.Write "test:" & CStr(True)`
or 
`Response.Write "test:" & Trim(True)`
with or w/o SetLocale?

Comment: No change when changing the locale and/or using `CStr` and `Trim`

Answer (score 3):

that is just like string concatenation works in vbscript.

from the [vbscript language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> "Whenever an expression is not a string, it is converted to a String
>   subtype. If both expressions are Null, result is also Null. However,
>   if only one expression is Null, that expression is treated as a
>   zero-length string ("") when concatenated with the other expression.
>   Any expression that is Empty is also treated as a zero-length string."

Comment: Obviously a type must change to string to be used as one, but it doesnt say "This happens in the windows language and cannot be changed".

Answer (score 2):

If the SetLocale didn't work, then I think your best bet is to create a function.

```
Function TF(B)
   If B Then
      TF = "True"
   Else
      TF = "False"
   End If
End Function
```

Then instead of saying this:

```
Response.Write "test:" & True
```

You'd say this:

```
Response.Write "test:" & TF(True)
```

Comment: As you could have read in the question, creating a function wont do. And it sure looks a lot like my own answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770025/in-asp-how-to-set-boolean-values-to-english?rq=1 that is in the related question sections

Comment: I saw your comment on that question after I posted here. And, I know a function isn't what you wanted, but it may be your only option. If you were willing to change all the True's to Trim(True), then wouldn't it be the same work to change it to TF(True).

Comment: Also, you don't say why you need the English form of True & False. If it's for printing to a file for later inputting where you need a standard, then how about using -1 & 0. CInt(TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

If classic ASP script (VBScript) runs on a non-English operating system, such as Italian, the "False" keyword is translated as "Falso".

I have to develop the code on the O.S. in English, but I need to put the code into production on an O.S. in Italian.

In VB (and other languages) generally in logic tests, 0 means [false] and everything that is not 0 (so 1, 2, etc.) means [true].

I solved it with a test:

```
<%
Dim BOOL_FALSO
    BOLL_FALSO = false 'Works well on develop English OS


Dim BOOL_VERO
    BOOL_VERO = true 'Works well on develop English OS

if BOOL_FALSO = "Falso" then BOOL_FALSO = 0 'Works well on production Italian OS
if BOOL_VERO  = "Vero"  then BOOL_VERO  = 1 'Works well on production Italian OS
%>
```

and below in the code you must use `BOOL_VERO` instead of [true] and the code works on both OS, English and Italian, without any other modification.

NB: translation occurs only in logical tests, in query strings, for example:

```
SELECT Archived FROM Books WHERE Archived=false
```

[false] does not translate to "Falso"

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting Response.LCID or Session.LCID to 1033 at the beginning of your page, but this also influences how others things (likes dates and currency variables) are displayed.

1033 is the Locale Id for the US

Comment: As said by @Tom Collins, That won't be of any help. In fact, **a Boolean remains a Boolean**, *whatever language was set on the system*. Once you convert this Boolean value to a STRING, then the ocalized String will be used ("True", "Vrai", "Verdadero", "Wahr", ...). The only solution is to test for the boolean variable being True, then return the text you need. Ex : `If (MyVar = True) then:Response.Write "True":else:Response.Write "False":end if`

Answer (score 0):

Attempt 2:

```
<%
arr=Array("False","True")

Response.Write True
Response.Write "<br /><br />"

Response.Write "" & arr( abs(True) ) & "<br />"
Response.Write "" & arr( abs(False) ) & "<br />"
%>
```

Comment: That is still adding something to the occurances of `true` and `false`. And in this case even more then just `PB(True)` from my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution if you dont mind changing regional settings to united states one. It involves changing the registry. This has been tested in windows 7 spanish and now it give native True/False instead of Verdadero/Falso.

1. Navigate to HKEY_USERS/.Default/Control Panel/International and take a nice picture with your phone in case you mess things up. you can also make a backup of the registry keys by clicking "international" and then File/export
2. Open a notepad and paste this inside (you can alternatively change values by hand one by one in the registry):

----------------- paste what is below this line -------------

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International]
"Locale"="00000409"
"LocaleName"="en-US"
"s1159"=""
"s2359"=""
"sCountry"="United States"
"sCurrency"="$"
"sDate"="/"
"sDecimal"="."
"sGrouping"="3;0"
"sLanguage"="ENU"
"sList"=","
"sLongDate"="dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"
"sMonDecimalSep"="."
"sMonGrouping"="3;0"
"sMonThousandSep"=","
"sNativeDigits"="0123456789"
"sNegativeSign"="-"
"sPositiveSign"=""
"sShortDate"="M/d/yyyy"
"sThousand"=","
"sTime"=":"
"sTimeFormat"="h:mm:ss tt"
"sShortTime"="h:mm tt"
"sYearMonth"="MMMM, yyyy"
"iCalendarType"="1"
"iCountry"="1"
"iCurrDigits"="2"
"iCurrency"="0"
"iDate"="0"
"iDigits"="2"
"NumShape"="1"
"iFirstDayOfWeek"="6"
"iFirstWeekOfYear"="0"
"iLZero"="1"
"iMeasure"="1"
"iNegCurr"="0"
"iNegNumber"="1"
"iPaperSize"="1"
"iTime"="0"
"iTimePrefix"="0"
"iTLZero"="0"

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\Geo]
"Nation"="244"
```

----------------- do not paste this line -------------

3. Save it as english.reg (or whatever.reg)
4. Double click it.

I didnt have to restart my computer for changes to take effect.

-------- UPDATE ----------

Does not work. If I make a blank asp page with this: <%=isnumeric(6)%> it answers True (in english) but as soon as I concatenate a True in a string it becames Verdadero again.

Answer (score 0):

I was "caught" too with this "issue".
Indeed, this is not an issue :

## THE PROBLEM (EXAMPLE)

I had the same problem when using a boolean data in a SQL Statement.
On my French server, my SQL statement was the following :

```
<%
'Set my boolean value
Dim myBoolean
myBoolean = True

'Set my SQL Statement
Dim MySQLStatement
MySQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyBooleanField = " & myBoolean
'=> Here, as MySQLStatement is a STRING, the boolean data was "converted/rendered" as a localized string. So that leads to this output :
'=> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyBooleanField = Vrai
'Obviously, that SQL Statement is incorrect, because the SQL Engine does NOT understand what is the "Vrai" word - It should be "True" instead.
%>
```

## THE EXPLANATIONS :

- It does not matter which regional settings are set on your Windows System : Nothing happens to the underlying data. A boolean data type **is STILL** a *BOOLEAN*, in English, or French, or German, Russian, Thai, ..or any language you want.
- The fact is that the data **is simply being RENDERED** as a localized *STRING* (like dates).

## THE SOLUTION

After a lot of reading over forums threads, the solution is not to change regional settings on the Windows system, nor changing Registry keys, nor changing Session.LCID, ...
The absolute and code-only **solution is to convert the Boolean value (True|False) to an Integer (0|1)**. Then, this Integer will be safely usable in a string, and will remain (0|1).

**Here is the safe way** to use/convert/render a Boolean value in a non-localized form : **Use an Integer value**.

```
<%
'Set my boolean value
Dim myBoolean
myBoolean = True

'Set my SQL Statement
Dim MySQLStatement
MySQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyBooleanField = " & BoolToInt(myBoolean)
'=> Here, as MySQLStatement is a STRING, and as the boolean data was previously "converted/rendered" as an integer, we got this correct SQL Statement :
'=> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyBooleanField = 1
'This SQL Statement is correct, as the SQL Engine DOES understand that 1 is a boolean.

'This Function Returns an INTEGER value based on a BOOLEAN value
Function BoolToInt(v)
    'INPUT:
    'v      Boolean value    

    'OUTPUT:
    'Integer (0|1)    

    Dim b_OUT
    b_OUT = v    

    'If the Input value is a "True" boolean value (in any language)
    if (b_OUT = True) then
        BoolToInt = cint(1)
    'If the Input value is a "False" boolean value (in any language)
    elseif (b_OUT = False) then
        BoolToInt = cint(0)
    end if
End Function 'BoolToInt
%>
```

I really hope it save your day !