# In asp, how to set boolean values to english?

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, boolean

When I run this:

```
    <%
    www = false
    response.write www
    response.write "UPDATE table SET domain='"&www&"' WHERE id=n"
    %>
```

I get this:

```
    false
    UPDATE table SET domain='Falso' WHERE id=n
```

Notice the 'Falso' word that is in Portuguese instead of English.

Is it possible to change the boolean values to English?

I have a Windows 2008 / IIS 7 in pt-BR.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boolean values in local language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760035/boolean-values-in-local-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll not be able to provide any more testing for this 'issue' anymore.

That's because I've made a decision to format my windows and install a new one now in english.. I did this because I'm running out of time, I need to put this server working as soon as possible..

But I want to thank everyone who contributed on finding the resolution for this problem =)

If anyone is having the same issue, please leave your comment, so the others can provide more options to try to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked just recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760035/boolean-values-in-local-language/15767841#15767841)

I don't have a good machine to test the following code, which came from a working solution. It forces the locality you need (of course you can change the locality to what you need it to be, if 1033 is not your goal)

```
<%
Response.Write FormatDateTime(Now) & "<br />"
oldLocale = SetLocale(1033) '1033=English(US)
Response.Write FormatDateTime(Now) & "<br />"
SetLocale oldLocale 
Response.Write FormatDateTime(Now) & "<br />"
%>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried this without success.

Comment: Tried the session.lcid too but didn't work as well.
But thanks for trying..
I guess the only way out would be installing my Windows in english! oh, microsoft, that sucks!

I think my problem is the same as this guy http://serverfault.com/questions/274964/iis-7-5-using-classic-asp-converts-a-boolean-value-to-a-string-in-the-local-lang

Comment: Sorry I can't test this myself, but what happens if you do this `response.write "UPDATE table SET domain='"& CStr(www) &"' WHERE id=n"` or this `response.write "UPDATE table SET domain='"& Trim(www) &"' WHERE id=n"`?

Comment: G.Stoynev the results: UPDATE table SET domain='Falso' WHERE id=n
UPDATE table SET domain='Falso' WHERE id=n 
Still in portuguese =/

Comment: How about setting Session.LCID during session setup or on every page, as in Session.LCID = 2057

Comment: I would also try Session.CodePage
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525649(v=vs.90).aspx). Sorry I am guessing, but I don't know enough to motivate myself to change one of my dev machines to a foreign locale to test this. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: as I said before the session.lcid didn't work.. 
the function session.codepage I think would only 'translate' the charset encoding, not the language itself.. thanks anyway man!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind changing the code, you could use a function to print the boolean value. For me thats not an option, but i'm starting to believe its the only way.

```
Function PB(pVal)
  If pVal Then
    PB = "true"
  Else
    PB = "false"
  End If
End Function

Response.Write "UPDATE table SET domain='"&PD(www)&"' WHERE id=n"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use string instead:

```
www = "false"
```

Then it won't be affected by regional settings.

If you want to keep working with actual boolean values, use Parameters instead of raw SQL.

Comment: I use boolean values on my whole application. It would not be practical at all to change the code, I'd rather reinstall the windows instead. Thanks anyway Shadow Wizard for the suggestion

Comment: What do you mean by 'use parameters insted of raw SQL'?

Comment: [This other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3370759/447356) contains code sample of using parameters in a SELECT statement. This requites much bigger change in code though.