# Is it possible to un-localize MSSQL-results in VBS?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, localization

Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology - I'm not into MSSQL or VBScript.

I have a given script implementing a SQL query containing

```
.. AND (rep.is_primary_replica is null or rep.is_primary_replica = ''True'' or rep.is_primary_replica = ''False'') ..
```

which returns no results on a *German* server only because `rep.is_primary_replica` seems to contain `''Wahr''` and `''Falsch''` instead of `''True''` and `''False''`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760035/boolean-values-in-local-language) is about an at least similar problem.

Unfortunately there is no `wtf` flag.

Is there a way to do that correctly?

Can I *disable* localization of string conversions? (in MS SQL Server? VBS?)

Comment: Are you sure it's a translation issue? Seems like you are testing for string literals. I don't think SQL server has a boolean datatype that works with `True` and `False`. Now if you are testing a varchar field, and it happens to contain `Wahr` and `Falsch` you'll have to choice but to test for those actual values. PS Why the double single quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't let printed values in the script confuse you. There is an implicit conversion from original value to string which depends on the client's (VBScript in your case I think) locale.

Type of the field `is_primary_replica` here must be `bit` if the `rep` is an instance of [sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-database-replica-states-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) view.

If this is the case, it's pointless to check a bit field is `Null`, or its value equal to `True` or `False`, there's no other possibility anyway.

It appears that you can safely remove this condition from the query.

If you insist to include it, use number literals instead.

```tsql
AND (rep.is_primary_replica is null or rep.is_primary_replica = 1 or rep.is_primary_replica = 0)
```

This is the proper way to query a bit field. With this way the server's or client's locale configuration won't cause any problems.

Comment: And yet - is it possible to have that implicit conversion always use English rather than the localized translations? I'm curious because a colleague of mine said he vaguely remembers there was such an option..

Comment: @frans Even if it were possible, do you really want to rely on an option that can simply be changed and break your program? To have a result `False` from an expression like `WScript.Echo CStr(False)` in VBScript, you need to make sure that your computer's locale is English. If you meant the SQL Server queries, it would be better to ask a new question with more details. Database administrators on the network can provide more accurate information.